# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, I am to print the maximum number of consecutive 1s if we replace any 0 to 1

Tags: python

I am trying to print the maximum number of consecutive 1s if we replace any 0 to 1 but I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
A = [0,1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 0]
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    if A[i] == 1:
        count = count +1
if count == len(A):
    print(count)
ans = 0
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    if A[i] == 0:
        L =0 
        R = 0
        for j in range(i-1, 0, -1):
            if A[j] == 1:
                L = L +1
            else:
                break
        for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
            if A[j] ==1:
                R = R +1
            else:
                break
        ans = max(L+R+1)
        print(ans)
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    ans = max(L+R+1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

python `max` is expecting a list of integers

```
max(n1, n2, ...)
```

<strike>You probably want to have
```
ans = max(L+1, R+1)
```</strike>

You need to store each instance of L+R+1 in a list, then compare when you have all instances.

Comment: for each 0 we are counting the 1s on the left(L) and on the right(R), and if we replace the 0 to 1 then the total will become (L+R+1)

Comment: you are correct